# Calculating a new column in Python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want apply simple operation on pandas dataframe to get percentage change for each row. I have data like this

```
colA    colB    colC    colD
39.5    41      41.5    40.5
15.5    17      17.5    16.5
21.5    23      23.5    22.5
40.5    42      42.5    41.5
9.5     11      11.5    10.5
26.5    28      28.5    27.5
```

My code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(((df.colA/ np.mean(df.iloc[:,2:], axis=1))-1)*100)

df['change'] = df.apply(lambda x: (((x.colA/ np.mean(x.iloc[:,2:], axis=1))-1)*100))
```

When I print the results it gives me exactly the thing I want, but when I do df.apply to create a column, it gives me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4279)
  File "pandas\src\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 404, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:8543)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Any suggestions ? Where I am doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output of your function is `Series` with same index as `df`, so simple assign it to new column:

```
df['change'] = (((df.colA/ np.mean(df.iloc[:,2:], axis=1))-1)*100)
print (df)
   colA  colB  colC  colD     change
0  39.5    41  41.5  40.5  -3.658537
1  15.5    17  17.5  16.5  -8.823529
2  21.5    23  23.5  22.5  -6.521739
3  40.5    42  42.5  41.5  -3.571429
4   9.5    11  11.5  10.5 -13.636364
5  26.5    28  28.5  27.5  -5.357143
```

Or use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(change=(((df.colA/ np.mean(df.iloc[:,2:], axis=1))-1)*100))
print (df)
   colA  colB  colC  colD     change
0  39.5    41  41.5  40.5  -3.658537
1  15.5    17  17.5  16.5  -8.823529
2  21.5    23  23.5  22.5  -6.521739
3  40.5    42  42.5  41.5  -3.571429
4   9.5    11  11.5  10.5 -13.636364
5  26.5    28  28.5  27.5  -5.357143
```

Also is possible use pandas functions only - [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) + [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) + [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) + [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) + 
[`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
df['change'] = df.colA.div(df.iloc[:,2:].mean(1)).sub(1).mul(100)
print (df)
   colA  colB  colC  colD     change
0  39.5    41  41.5  40.5  -3.658537
1  15.5    17  17.5  16.5  -8.823529
2  21.5    23  23.5  22.5  -6.521739
3  40.5    42  42.5  41.5  -3.571429
4   9.5    11  11.5  10.5 -13.636364
5  26.5    28  28.5  27.5  -5.357143
```